# Strange Problem with EditText() - Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext, trim

I'm facing this odd issue:

```
    // definition
    var myEditText: EditText? = null

    .
    .
    .

    // instantiation
    myEditText = EditText(this)
    myEditText?.setSingleLine(true)
    myEditText?.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW)
    myEditText?.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED)
    myEditText?.setPadding(10, 0, 10, 0)
    myEditText?.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL
    myEditText?.inputType = InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_CHARACTERS
    myEditText?.setOnFocusChangeListener { view, hasFocus -> ...

    rootView.addView(myEditText)

    .
    .
    .

    if (myEditText?.text == null || myEditText?.text.trim() == "") {

        println("it's blank!")   // doesn't execute

    } else {

        println(">>>" + myEditText?.text.trim() + "<<<")

    }

    // output: >>><<<
```

The **EditText()** control has been instantiated properly and appears correctly on the screen. I'm able to type in text and it will return the entries correctly.

But why can't it recognize that the text box is empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
myEditText?.text.toString()
```

You should use [**`toString()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Object.html#toString())

> Returns a string representation of the object. In general, the
>   toString method returns a string that "textually represents" this
>   object. The result should be a concise but informative representation
>   that is easy for a person to read. It is recommended that all
>   subclasses override this method.

Comment: That did it. Don't know how I'd missed that. Thank you.